# How to group grid with one item in the group in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using c#.net desktop application

I have gridview that looks like this

```
ibengin   iend   code    preferredText     Affirmation    tag     codeScheme    Value
1         10             Kitkat            Yes            Choc    
11        15             Mars              Yes            Choc    
16        20             Bounty            Yes            Choc    
21        27     A1      Kitkat            Yes            Choc    USA
28        32             Bounty            Yes            Choc    
33        47             Bounty            No             Choc    
48        61     A1      Kitkat            Yes            Choc    USA
62        65     B7      Mars              Yes            Choc    UK
66        77             Kitkat            Yes            Choc    USA
78        81             Kitkat            Yes            Choc
```

I want it to be grouped as follows

```
Affirmation   PreferredText   Count    Value   CodingScheme   Code    Positions
Yes           Kitkat          5                USA            A1     1:10,21:27,48:61,66:77,78:81
Yes           Mars            2                UK             B7     11:15,62:65
Yes           Bounty          2                                      16:20,28:32
No            Bounty          1                                      33:47
```

I have almost finished it, but one problem remained.

I want to use the first value of codeScheme and code as shown above

Here is the code that I have done so far.

appreciate any help

```
    var lstInfo = grdBreakDown.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                               .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow)                   // either..
                               .Where(x => x.Cells["Tag"].Value.ToString() == Tag) //..or or both
                               .GroupBy(x => new
                               {
                                   grpAffirmation = x.Cells["Affirmation"].Value.ToString(),
                                   grpPreferredText = x.Cells["preferredText"].Value.ToString(),
                                   grpValue = (cbxValue.Checked ? x.Cells["Value"].Value.ToString() : "")
                               })
                               .Select(y => new
                               {
                                   Affirmation = y.Key.grpAffirmation,
                                   PreferredText = y.Key.grpPreferredText,
                                   Count = y.Count(),//.ToString(),
                                   Value = y.Key.grpValue,
                                   Positions = string.Join(",", y.Select(i => i.Cells["ibegin"].Value.ToString() + ":" + i.Cells["iend"].Value.ToString()))
                               })
                               .OrderByDescending(y => y.Count)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: Is grid bound to a source like a DataTable?  Usually it is easier to write the code using the binding source.

Comment: @jdweng this is my heritage no chance for changing now

Comment: Just a suggestion.  Can't tell from code how you added values to the grid.  The only way of grouping by a list (like null and A1) is to create a list and then use Contains.  In this case it may be easier just to add the A1 to the grid when it is empty.  Then do the grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
    var lstInfo = grdBreakDown.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                               .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow)                   // either..
                               .Where(x => x.Cells["Tag"].Value.ToString() == Tag) //..or or both
                               .GroupBy(x => new
                               {
                                   grpAffirmation = x.Cells["Affirmation"].Value.ToString(),
                                   //grpCodingScheme = x.Cells["codingScheme"].Value.ToString(),
                                   //grpCode = x.Cells["code"].Value.ToString(),
                                   grpPreferredText = x.Cells["preferredText"].Value.ToString(),
                                   grpValue = (cbxValue.Checked ? x.Cells["Value"].Value.ToString() : "")
                               })
                               .Select(y => new
                               {
                                   Affirmation = y.Key.grpAffirmation,
                                   CodingScheme = string.Join(",", y.Select(i => i.Cells["codingScheme"].Value.ToString()).Distinct()).TrimEnd(','),
                                   Code = string.Join(",", y.Select(i => i.Cells["code"].Value.ToString()).Distinct()).TrimEnd(','),
                                   PreferredText = y.Key.grpPreferredText,
                                   Count = y.Count(),//.ToString(),
                                   Value = y.Key.grpValue,
                                   Positions = string.Join(",", y.Select(i => i.Cells["ibegin"].Value.ToString() + ":" + i.Cells["iend"].Value.ToString()))
                               })
                               .OrderByDescending(y => y.Count)
                               .ToList();
```